# Caching data by using the result of first running operation

Tags: c#, lazy

My code handles concurrent requests by waiting for the result of an already running operation. Requests for data may come in simultaneously with same/different credentials (including empty credentials).

For each unique set of credentials there can be at most one `GetCurrentInternal` call in progress, with the result from that one call returned to all queued waiters when it is ready.

```
private static readonly Credentials EmptyCredentials = new Credentials
{
    SqlCredentials = null,
    ExchangeCredentials = null,
};

public AgentMetadata GetCurrent(Credentials credentials)
{
    var agentMetadata = new Lazy<AgentMetadata>(() => GetCurrentInternal(credentials));

    var lazyMetadata = (Lazy<AgentMetadata>)MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting(
                       (credentials ?? EmptyMetadataCredentials).ToString(),
                       agentMetadata,
                       DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));

    try
    {
        return (lazyMetadata ?? agentMetadata).Value;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        _logger.ErrorException(ex, "An error occurs during getting full metadata");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Is it thread safe? Do I have a bugs? How to create a good key for the `AddOrGetExisting`?

`Credentials` its a `DataContract` that contains other `DataContract` like `SqlCredentials`, `ExchangeCredentials`. And they contains their own `strings` like `user_name` and `password`.

Comment: Since the method is public, the users can pass the credentials parameter as null. It is best to test the parameter value and replace it with EmptyCredentials if it is null

Comment: Is Credentials your class?

Comment: @OguzOzgul Yes, its my class. It contains other DataContracts like SqlCredentials, ExchangeCredentials

Comment: Then, you can consider exposing the EmptyCredentials as a static property of Credentials which returns new Credentials() { SqlCredentials = null, ExchangeCredentials = null }; Just like String.Empty. You should anyways check if the passed credentials parameter is null, and throw ArgumentNullException or replace it with Credentials.EmptyCredentials

Comment: And if you want to execute only one GetDataInternal() for all the null credentials, you should also make that EmptyCredentials instance singleton to always return the same instance

Comment: @OguzOzgul But he already do this things. I think he wondered about thread safe and implementation of key value inside AddOrGetExisting

Comment: @OguzOzgul  As I said for each unique set of credentials there can be at most one GetCurrentInternal call in progress.

Comment: @OguzOzgul So I use Lazy evaluation

Comment: @OguzOzgul But I'm not sure if my code is thread safe and how to create <key,value> inside MemoryCache, if I have a complex object like Credentials

Comment: @OguzOzgul I know how to  work with ConccurentDictionary, but I dont now how to create <key,value> for a MemoryCache

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko seems like this is the same assignment as yours, why don't we let him [check your question here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113827/handle-concurrent-request-by-waiting-the-result-of-an-already-running-operation/113859?noredirect=1#comment213516_113859)

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko yes he is already doing it, but in a way that violates "encapsulation" by assigning null to Sql and Exchange credentials. What if a new type of credential is intorduced in Credentials class? That will also be null by default, ok, but still, that's why I recommend moving the EmptyCredentials to Credentials class.

Comment: The null check for credentials object should still be implemented. Having a EmptyCreentials property does not guarantee the consumers are going to use it.

Comment: The code seems thread safe, but I will test it as I did for your question but a little bit later

Comment: @OguzOzgul Waiting for your test results

Comment: @OguzOzgul it seems that you have an answer in the comments here. Please try to post answers as answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it seems thread safe.

I run a test to prove it which I give the details at the bottom, but first are some code review comments.

1. The code is missing the `Credentials` class which I think is also important for the review. The cache items are added with keys `credentials.ToString()` and it is important for this method to return the same value for `Credentials` objects having the same credential values, and distinct values for `Credentials` instances with different credential values. Is it?
2. Naming conventions. Class names should be PascalCase and the class `AgentMetadata` violates this rule. Should be `AgentMetaData`
3. To achieve better encapsulation and seperation of concerns, (The creation of an empty credential object should be a concern for the Credentials class, which has control over the internals of itself) instead of having a `static readonly Credentials EmptyCredentials` field in this class, it is better to have a `public static readonly Credentials Empty` field (or property getter) in Credentials class.

Instead of this:

```
Credentials empty = (credentials ?? EmptyMetadataCredentials);
```

Isn't it better to have this?

```
Credentials empty = (credentials ?? Credentials.Empty);
```

4. The variable names `agentMetadata` and `lazyMetadata` are not descriptive enough.

This is somewhat confusing:

```
return (lazyMetadata ?? agentMetadata).Value;
```

Having names like the following might eliminate that confusion:

```
var newLazyInstance = new Lazy<AgentMetadata>(() => GetCurrentInternal(credentials));

var cachedLazyInstance = (Lazy<AgentMetadata>)MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting(
                           (credentials ?? EmptyMetadataCredentials).ToString(),
                           newLazyInstance,
                           DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));

return (cachedLazyInstance ?? newLazyInstance).Value;
```

And here are the results of the test, which shows the `GetCurrentInternal` method is invoked a total of 5 times for all the 100 threads.

The test created 100 threads which access the `GetCurrent` method randomly within 500 ms. There is another thread for removing the item from the cache in 100 ms continuously (This is because, the cache policy doesn't seem to effectively remove the item at the exact point of time of expiration).

The `GetCurrentInternal` method lasts for a random time between 0 and 500 ms

With the following results, it can be seen that the `GetCurrentInternal` method is invoked a total of 5 times (which is the number of the cache not containing a `Lazy` instance for the given credentials, first one because the cache is empty, and for 4 more times because it is removed from the cache)

I can't help myself thinking why the `AddOrGetExisting` of `MemoryCache` returns `null`  when the item is added to the cache. This would have been implemented differently (as returning the added instance as ConcurrentDictionary does)

```
T:47    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 145,68
T:13    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 146,44
T:20    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 146,54
T:26    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 147,45
T:71    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 148,46
T:62    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 148,55
T:53    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 149,37
T:5 M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 146,68
T:22    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:True  150,66
T:31    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 150,18
T:63    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 154,58
T:50    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 157,15
T:27    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 182,13
T:67    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 182,33
T:43    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 182,18
T:32    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 182,13
T:3 M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 187,24
T:55    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 194,8
T:29    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 197,13
T:28    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 214,17
T:4 M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 221,11
T:84    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 228,12
T:78    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 232,09
T:19    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 235,1
T:66    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 238,1
T:7 M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 242,14
T:61    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 245,11
T:49    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 246,15
T:23    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 250,08
T:85    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 251,1
T:81    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 254,1
T:98    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 254,12
T:44    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 254,13
T:91    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 255,25
T:65    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 257,2
T:59    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 259,33
T:56    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 269,1
T:34    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 271,11
T:89    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 271,12
T:41    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 279,12
T:100   M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 280,12
T:11    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 290,11
T:17    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 292,08
T:58    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 293,1
T:14    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 297,09
T:90    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:True  303,12
T:75    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 312,15
T:46    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 318,17
T:45    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 321,11
T:10    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 322,1
T:92    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 328,1
T:80    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 339,12
T:8 M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 341,11
T:51    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 342,11
T:74    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 343,11
T:86    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 351,12
T:68    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 352,11
T:95    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 354,1
T:72    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 359,11
T:48    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 360,11
T:18    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 364,1
T:6 M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 374,12
T:35    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 377,09
T:15    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 377,11
T:93    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 378,1
T:33    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 379,1
T:9 M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 390,12
T:39    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 391,09
T:12    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 395,11
T:24    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:True  401,11
T:40    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 402,11
T:30    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 404,09
T:70    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 411,11
T:102   M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 412,1
T:52    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 413,11
T:57    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 417,1
T:37    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 426,13
T:69    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 428,1
T:16    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 432,11
T:21    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 438,13
T:96    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 441,11
T:38    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 442,09
T:54    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 456,18
T:82    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 465,12
T:76    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 466,11
T:25    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 470,11
T:36    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 477,09
T:73    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 483,12
T:42    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 483,13
T:101   M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 491,13
T:64    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 494,12
T:60    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:True  502,11
T:97    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 528,2
T:24    M:GetCurrentInternal    E:Invoked   R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    547,76
T:24    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    548,3
T:70    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    548,36
T:40    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    548,32
T:57    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    549,27
T:21    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    561,53
T:36    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    574,77
T:102   M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    548,4
T:38    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    563,24
T:101   M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    575,21
T:77    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 579,16
T:25    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    571,16
T:54    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    567,6
T:73    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    574,79
T:42    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    574,8
T:76    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    567,61
T:37    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    554,64
T:82    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    567,6
T:52    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    548,38
T:64    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    575,44
T:16    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    557,74
T:94    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 587,92
T:69    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    556,54
T:96    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    562,78
T:30    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=1    548,35
T:88    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:True  616,19
T:103   M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 631,16
T:90    M:GetCurrentInternal    E:Invoked   R:AgentMetadata_ID=2    642,16
T:90    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=2    642,37
T:80    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=2    644,54
T:72    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    648,45
T:47    M:GetCurrentInternal    E:Invoked   R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    645,16
T:47    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    650,61
T:26    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    652,63
T:22    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    654,89
T:9 M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    654,43
T:86    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    646,88
T:18    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    648,75
T:6 M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    649,06
T:15    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    650,84
T:74    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    646,62
T:53    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    658,94
T:31    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    662,34
T:46    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=2    642,4
T:62    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    652,69
T:95    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    646,88
T:67    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    664,69
T:71    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    660,52
T:93    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    650,84
T:45    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=2    642,4
T:50    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    652,69
T:23    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    677,68
T:78    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    672,49
T:66    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    672,5
T:4 M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    671,15
T:10    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=2    642,44
T:5 M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    657,11
T:65    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    678,46
T:29    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    669,35
T:81    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    679,46
T:33    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    649,06
T:92    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=2    642,46
T:14    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    688,26
T:13    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    652,62
T:17    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    688,25
T:28    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    671,12
T:89    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    684,54
T:11    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    686,67
T:100   M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    686,67
T:58    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    688,25
T:61    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    676,52
T:20    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    660,51
T:34    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    684,53
T:68    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    646,88
T:85    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    674,46
T:44    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    677,66
T:49    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    673,36
T:32    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    667,5
T:3 M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    669,31
T:41    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    686,66
T:39    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    654,43
T:7 M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    672,5
T:48    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    648,47
T:12    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    655,34
T:19    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    672,5
T:83    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 672,09
T:98    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    680,64
T:63    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    662,4
T:91    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    677,96
T:8 M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=2    644,56
T:75    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=2    642,38
T:43    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    665,46
T:27    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    662,37
T:59    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    680,63
T:55    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    669,34
T:99    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 695,73
T:51    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    646,62
T:56    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    684,53
T:84    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    672,24
T:87    M:GetCurrent    E:AddOrGetExisting.Added?   R:False 691,88
T:35    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=3    650,56
T:60    M:GetCurrentInternal    E:Invoked   R:AgentMetadata_ID=4    988,26
T:60    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=4    988,88
T:77    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=4    988,96
T:94    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=4    989,03
T:97    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=4    988,97
T:88    M:GetCurrentInternal    E:Invoked   R:AgentMetadata_ID=5    1050,3
T:88    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=5    1050,85
T:83    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=5    1050,94
T:87    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=5    1052,18
T:103   M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=5    1050,91
T:99    M:GetCurrent    E:Lazy.Value    R:AgentMetadata_ID=5    1050,97
```

Comment: 1. Yes, its true. update the question

Comment: How can I implement method `GetKey` that return the same value for Credentials objects that having the same credential values, and distinct values for Credentials instances with different credential values?

Comment: Its really important to have this method. @Oguz if you show how to implement this method, it would be very good extension for your answer. Because credential.ToString() doesnt work.

Comment: @ipetr: This problem would be outside the scope of this site - CodeReview is about reviewing existing working code. If you have code which doesn't exist yet or doesn't work this is off topic here.